# Without using the binomial expansion. Show that $(\sqrt 3 +i)^n + (\sqrt 3 -i)^n$ is real for any positive integer $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that $(\sqrt 3 +i)^n + (\sqrt 3 -i)^n$ is REAL for any positive integer $n$. My initial thought was to use trial and error using values $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ but that does not seem like a thorough proof. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Those $1$'s should be $i$'s, right?

Comment: Yeah cheers for spotting that David, changed it accordingly.

Comment: Sure about the result? Try $n=4$, say.

Comment: Actually, very few complex numbers $z$ are such that $(z)^n+(\bar z)^n$ is positive for every positive integer $n$...

Comment: The title says "real" however the question says "positive", I think the title is the question?

Comment: @Alexis Good catch. Then I guess my previous comment gives a solution... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think can rewrite $C=|r|e^{i\theta},C^*=|r|e^{-i\theta}$, and use $C^n+C^{*n}=|r|^n (e^{ni\theta}+e^{-ni\theta})$ and use $e^{ia}=\cos (a)+i\sin (a)$

Comment: How does I use $e^{ia}=\cos (a)+i\sin (a)$ to help?

Comment: @Pstar007 I think $e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}=\cos (n\theta)+\cos (-n\theta)+i\left(\sin (n\theta)+\sin (-n\theta)\right)=2\cos (n\theta)$

Comment: Wicked, done and dusted. Cheers, nice one alexis!

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** A complex number $z$ is real if and only if $z=\overline{z}.$

(I'm not sure for the positive part)

Comment: I made a mistake when copying and pasting before I posted my question so no need to worry about the positive part. Thanks C.Dubussy

Comment: How would you show this when the question is in binomial form?

Comment: You can use the fact that for any complexes $z$ and $w$ : $\overline{z+w} = \overline{z}+\overline{w}$ and $\overline{z\cdot w} = \overline{z}\cdot\overline{w}$.

Answer (score 2):

$z^n + \bar z ^n = z^n + \overline{z^n} = 2\operatorname{Re}z^n\in\mathbb R$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/582930)

Comment: @Apurv, please elaborate. The question is to show that sum of the form $z^n+\bar z ^n$ is real, yes?

Comment: yes. Explain to the user why the result you write is true, for he is  unaware of it (evident from the question). Don't just answer for the sake of votes. Answer so that the OP doesn't have a doubt of that kind ever again.

Comment: Wow, ok. From false to unclear sure is improvement. Let's leave to the OP to request clarification if needed. @Apurv. Why don't you point out what exactly is missing for the answer to deserve votes.

Comment: look at Michael Hardy's answer below to get what I am saying. These are the kind of answers that satisfy the OP, given his limited knowledge. Get it?

Comment: Btw, if you were the one serially downvoting my answers for revenge, then you are a fool for it has been reversed.

Comment: @Apurv, Huh, what? So, your input to the whole matter is advice to look at another answer. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Yup, for you dont understand anything. look at another answer, compare the two and go to sleep.

Comment: @Apurv, very funny of you to say that, since you were first not to understand what I wrote in the first place, hence voting for deletion. The aim was simplicity and elegance of the argument, clearly missed on you. If you think another answer is better, go upvote it and leave me out of it in the future for your manners are poor and your arguments lacking. Good day to you and hopefully good riddance for me.

Comment: A serial down-voter wants to teach me mannerisms for this site. Good.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $x_n=(\sqrt 3 +i)^n + (\sqrt 3 -i)^n$, then one can show that $x_{n}=2\sqrt3 x_{n-1}-4x_{n=2}$.

$x_0=2, x_1=2\sqrt3$ are both real, the reals are closed under $\pm$, so by induction, $x_n$ is real for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are real then the complex conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$.

If you add a complex number to its complex conjugate, you get a real  number: $$(a+bi) + (a-bi)= 2a.$$

So if you can show that $(\sqrt 3 -i)^n$ is the complex conjugate of $(\sqrt 3 +i)^n$, then you've got it.

You get $(\sqrt3+i)^n$ by multiplying:
$$
\underbrace{(\sqrt3+i)\cdots\cdots(\sqrt3+i)}_\text{$n$ factors}. \tag 1
$$
If you take the complex conjugate of each factor **separately** you get
$$
\underbrace{(\sqrt3-i)\cdots\cdots(\sqrt3-i)}_\text{$n$ factors} = (\sqrt3-i)^n. \tag 2
$$
So the question is: If you conjugate each factor separately, do you get the same complex number as if you conjugate the product?

\begin{align}
(a-bi)(c-di) & = (ac-bd) - i(ad+bc) \\[10pt]
= {} &  \Big( \text{the conjugate of } (ac-bd) + i (ad+bc) \Big) = (a+bi)(c+di).
\end{align}
So the answer to that question is "yes".  Therefore $(2)$ is the conjugate of $(1)$.